# PE file format and virtual memory

Tags: paging, execution, virtual-memory, portable-executable

I still can't establish a relationship between the PE executable and the virtual address space. I can't find resources that can help me understand how the OS (WINDOWS) takes a PE file and executes it in virtual memory (i do understand a little bit about virtual-physical memory translation but i can't see the whole image). I need some analogy to understand & i need a full example of executing a PE file, i also want to understand the  difference in the layout of a program on HDD (as a PE), on virtual memory & on real physical memory !! please, beside your answers suggest me good readings about the subject.

Comment: Not sure whether you have already read this, as far as I remember this is the book that talks about the internals [CLR Via C#](https://www.amazon.com/CLR-via-4th-Developer-Reference/dp/0735667454)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not (yet) a programming question. It is about operating system concepts. Maybe you can rework it as a programming question if you describe what program you are trying to write.